# Can't get mottie jQuery keyboard to highlight chosen key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, keyboard

Link to Mottie: https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard

I'm using Mottie keyboard with "navigation" and "mobile" extensions. It works fine except the "current key" is not being highlighted. I can navigate on the keyboard and upon clicking enter, it gets displayed, but I can't visually see which key is selected.

According to the documentation and working examples, having the snippet I have in "style" should do the trick, but it doesn't change anything.

My HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">

 <title>Virtual Keyboard Mobile Demo</title>

 <!-- demo -->
 <link href="css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- jQuery & jQuery UI + theme (required) -->
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

 <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

 <!-- keyboard widget css & script (required) -->
 <link href="css/keyboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="js/jquery.keyboard.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.keyboard.extension-navigation.js"></script>

 <!-- keyboard extensions (optional) -->
 <script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

 <!--
 <script src="../js/jquery.keyboard.extension-typing.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/jquery.keyboard.extension-autocomplete.js"></script>
 -->
 <script src="js/jquery.keyboard.extension-mobile.js"></script>

 <style>
 html head + body .ui-btn.ui-btn-c:hover,
 html head + body .ui-btn.ui-btn-c.ui-btn-hover,
 html head + body .ui-btn.ui-btn-c:active,
 html head + body .ui-btn.ui-btn-c.ui-btn-active {
  background-color: #f7931e;
  border-color: #a37a00;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffcc33;
 }

.ui-keyboard-button.ui-state-active.ui-state-hover {
  border: 1px solid #fff !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1em 1px #ffba2b inset !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1em 1px #ffba2b inset !important;
  box-shadow: 1px 1em 1px #ffba2b inset !important;
}
/* Class added to indicate the virtual keyboard has navigation focus */
.hasFocus {
  border-color: #59b4d4 !important;
}
 </style>

 <!-- initialize keyboard (required) -->
</head>
<body id="mobile">
  <div id="wrap"> <!-- wrapper only needed to center the input -->
   <!-- keyboard input -->
   <label for="keyboard"></label>
<input id="keyboard" name="keyboard" type="text">
  </div> <!-- End wrapper -->

 <script>
 $(function() {

  $('#keyboard')
   .keyboard({
   })
   /* initial setup for mobile extension */
   .addMobile({
    // keyboard wrapper theme
    container    : { theme:'b' },
    // theme added to all regular buttons
    buttonMarkup : { theme:'b', shadow:'true', corners:'true' },
    // theme added to all buttons when they are being hovered
    buttonHover  : { theme:'a' },
    // theme added to action buttons (e.g. tab, shift, accept, cancel);
    // parameters here will override the settings in the buttonMarkup
    buttonAction : { theme:'c' },
    // theme added to button when it is active (e.g. shift is down)
    // All extra parameters will be ignored
    buttonActive : { theme:'c' }
   });

   $('#keyboard')
    .keyboard({
    })
    .addNavigation({
     position   : [0,0],     // set start position [row-number, key-index]
     toggleMode : true,     // true = navigate the virtual keyboard, false = navigate in input/textarea
     focusClass : 'hasFocus' // css class added to the keyboard when toggle mode is on
    });
});
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone with experience using it notice what's wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it! Putt this in styling instead:

```
<style>
    html head + body .ui-navbutton.ui-navbutton-c:hover,
    html head + body .ui-navbutton.ui-navbutton-c.ui-navbutton-hover,
    html head + body .ui-navbutton.ui-navbutton-c:active,
    html head + body .ui-navbutton.ui-navbutton-c.ui-navbutton-active {
        border-color: #a37a00;
        color: #fff !important;
    }

    html head+body button.ui-keyboard-button.ui-state-hover {
        border: 1px solid #830000 !important;
        background-color: #999999 !important;
    }
    /* Class added to indicate the virtual keyboard has navigation focus */
    .hasFocus {
        border-color: #59b4d4 !important;
    }
    .navbutton {
        line-height: 30px;
        margin: 2px;
        padding: 5px;
        border: #333 1px solid;
    }
    </style>
```